# How to connect azure mysql server with nodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, azure

I am trying to connect to a remote mysql server with nodejs

So far I am able to connect with mysql workbench 8.0, so no problem with mysql server. And I can easily connect to my local mysql-server (with "mysql2" module).

Here is something I've been trying to connect with remote mysql server provided by Azure. I followed the guides that is provided.

```js
const mysql = require("mysql");
const fs = require("fs")

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.MYSQL_SERVER_HOST,
    user: process.env.MYSQL_SERVER_USER,
    password: process.env.MYSQL_SERVER_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.MYSQL_SERVER_DATABASE,
    port:3306,
    ssl: { ca: fs.readFileSync("./certificates/DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt.pem")}
});

// This is how I am connecting to my local mysql-server which is working fine
// // const connection = mysql.createConnection({
//     host: 'localhost',
//     user: 'root',
//     password: process.env.LOCAL_MYSQL_SERVER_PASSWORD,
//     database: 'db',
//     port: '3306'
// });

connection.connect((error) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log("mysql error")
        console.log(error)
    }
    else {
        console.log("Mysql Ready")
    }
});

module.exports = connection;
```

Here I am using **mysql** package because many articles on web suggested it but I even used **mysql2** and nothing happened. I even changed the networking setting and allowed my IP address for access(this wasn't necessary though).

**Error logs:**

```
mysql error
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at Connection._handleConnectTimeout (path\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:409:13)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:641:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at Socket._onTimeout (node:net:516:8)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (path\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (path\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (path\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:116:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (path\packnary\database\mysql.js:26:12)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18) {
  errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  fatal: true
}
```

Comment: Can you connect through a client to mysql without the code?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. I am able to connect from mysql workbenth running on my local computer.

Answer (score 1):

I connected Azure SQL database to the nodejs without using code.

I followed below procedure:

I have created azure blank nodeJs webapp in visual studio.

[image]

It run successfully. after that I go to overview of the webapp and selected connected services and clicked on a **add a service dependency option** and searched for azure sql database.

Image for reference:

[image]

[image]

select the azure sql data and click on next button.
login to azure account and select which database we need to connect.

Image for reference:

[image]

Enter the details required in the next window and click on next.

Image for reference:

[image]

Select the changes according to the requirements and click on next.

Image for reference:

[image]

It is connected successfully.

Image for reference:

[image]

[image]